# Currency format standard for Square?

Tags: square-connect

What is the currency standard for Square's developer API and where can I find the reference for it?

```
{
  "amount": 50,
  "currency_code": "USD"
}
```

In example [this page](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/build-basics/working-with-monetary-amounts) references the amount and currency though it does not clarify how to format currency formats, e.g. USD is the United States Dollar, what about the Canadian Dollar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your reference link: "Square represents the exchange as a Money object with a specific currency in ISO 4217 format and a positive or negative amount, where the amount is given in the smallest denomination of the given currency.". It means, you should use `ISO 4217` for currency code. For Canadian Dollar it will be `CAD`.